# bootstrap toggle button minimal example

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

I'm looking for a minimal example of HTML, css and js of a working bootstrap toggle button. I want to be able to read the current state (pressed or not) in javascript.

Edit: The issue is that is reverts to the unpressed state when you click outside the button.

The minimal example from [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/) (css added) does not work in my browser (Chrome).

My HTML/css:

```css
button {
  background-color: #e3a !important; /* pink */
}

button:active,
button:focus,
[role="button"][aria-pressed="true"] {
  background-color: blue !important; /* orange */
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <!-- from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/ -->
    <head>
        <title>bootstrap toggle button</title>
        <!-- use bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off">Toggle button</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The only thing I'm asking for is to make the button work as on [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/).

Comment: You can use event listeners on your button for this.

Comment: @Imperyum Let me rephrase my answer: For reading the button state, yes of course I can add the listeners. But that's not the issue I'm having. Did you check the example? The button in my example remains pressed after the mouse click (I updated the button color to make it more visible). BUT, it reverts to the unpressed value when you click elsewhere, which is not the way it should work and it is neither how it works on bootstrap's page. It should only change its state when clicking on it. What goes wrong?

Comment: You are presently trying to remove the focus of the button by clicking on the button again. This is not how bootstrap is intended to work. If you want to have a button that acts like a checkbox, use bootstrap checkboxes or switches and change the style of them. Here is the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#checkbox-toggle-buttons. You can also use event listeners to add or remove a class that puts style on your button as I said earlier.

Comment: Hi Imperyum, thanks for your answer. I'm sorry if I'm not clear about what I want to obtain (I'm not a native speaker of English either). I'm not looking for a checkbox type solution, because in the app I'm writing the button will select a brush with which you paint on an HTML canvas. So it should remain pushed in while drawing on the canvas and go back to its normal state by clicking on it again or by hitting ESC. Bootstrap documentation shows 2 buttons with this behaviour on their documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#toggle-states

Comment: I'm trying to get just that behaviour in my example, but on the above bootstrap page it works, and in my example it does not. Moreover, the bootstrap documentation you referred me to says: _Visually, these checkbox toggle buttons are identical to the button plugin toggle buttons. However, they are conveyed differently by assistive technologies: the checkbox toggles will be announced by screen readers as “checked”/“not checked” (since, despite their appearance, they are fundamentally still checkboxes), whereas the button plugin toggle buttons will be announced as “button”/“button pressed”._